# Is it possible render `page not found` with 404 http code without redirect?

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, vue-router, vue-storefront, vue-server-renderer

I'm using `vue-storefront`.
I need render 404 page without redirect and with 404 http code.
They are using `vue-router` + `vue-server-renderer`
I'm trying to catch 404 error, then rendering my component `PageNotFound`, setting status 404 to response and returning html.
After that my html replaced empty component (for example Category)
Or works correct but url (in browser) changing to `*/page-not-found`.
Any ideas ?
Thanks.